# Intraday Trading: Buy & Sell same stock but different volumes

Tags: stocks, trading, selling

If I sell 100 stocks of a company and buy 50 of the same company on the same day, will that 50 stocks be considered Intraday Trading?

Comment: "considered Intraday trading" for what purpose? Tax? Risk? Margin? Something else? What specifically are you concerned about?

Comment: Are you concerned about pattern day trader rules?  https://www.finra.org/investors/learn-to-invest/advanced-investing/day-trading-margin-requirements-know-rules

Comment: @DStanley Yes, Tax and brokerage (often high compared to delivery).

Answer (score 1):

If you buy and sell an option or an equity on the same day, it's a day trade.